# AssertJ: negating isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively

Tags: java, junit5, assertj

I have this code for checking if an object is equals to another one comparing all fields recursively using JUnit 5 and AssertJ:

```
assertThat(financialDataContainer2.getStandardisedBooking())
    .isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively(initialBooking);
```

How can you have an assertion in AssertJ which is the negation of this one? Basically I want to be able to check if two objects are **not** equal by comparing recursively all fields.

Comment: You want to assert that all fields are different  or at least one field is ?

Comment: @davidxxx yes, correct

Comment: the one or the second ? :)

Comment: @davidxxx The method `isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively` checks all fields for equality. If one field is not equal, then it returns false. Inverting this logic: if at least one single field is not equal then the implementation I am targeting should return true. So: "at least one field is".

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to 
[How do I negate assertions in AssertJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37994008/how-do-i-negate-assertions-in-assertj/56162863#56162863)

In your case the code would be:

```
assertThat(Collections.singleton(actual)).noneSatisfy(actual -> 
  assertThat(actual).isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively(unexpected)
);
```